# How to generate rows and columns of a grid in WPF MVVM without editing the view?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I understand that the idea behind MVVM is to separate the *View* from the *Viewmodel* and that code-behind in the *View* is a bad thing.

This is how I used to generate a specific number of columns when I didn't follow the MVVM (xaml.cs).

```
for (int i = 0; i < Constants.GRID_COLUMN_NUMBER; i++)
{
    ColumnDefinition tempColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
    gridName.ColumnDefinitions.Add(tempColumn);
}
```

Since accessing the grid from *ViewModel* to generate rows/columns is a bad thing, what would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Would using a user-control with a code-behind be an acceptable solution?

Comment: "that code-behind in the View is a bad thing" - ???. If you say you understand that, care to expalin WHY is it so?

Comment: "*separate the View from the Viewmodel*" ok, but "*code-behind in the View is a bad thing*" is a big misconception. MVVM says nothing about the latter.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with code behind in an MVVM context, so long as it's used to make the view work. What goes against MVVM is code behind related to business logic or other data related functionality.

Comment: I was taught at uni that if I were to follow MVVM, I should have no code in View code-behind. Judging by your tone I can only assume that there is code that is allowed to reside in View. I do know that not all code is exempt from View, but I'm not sure if what I need is.

Comment: "*no code in View code-behind*" makes no sense. As soon as you create a control with properties or when you attach event handler methods, code behind is unavoidable. Don't take this as a dogma.

Comment: Generating columns for a grind should be in the View, because it clearly is related to the what it looks like for a user. So you are fine here. Keep in mind view, viewmodel and model are all part of the user interface layer. The core logic is even behind this. In the model part you essentially structure the data and the viewmodel contains to the logic for the user to interact with the data. The view is what it looks like, so it is xaml related (if you use WPF).

Answer (score -1):

You can use behaviors for that purpose. You don't have to add code behind to your View, you just create a dedicated class that is responsible for generating the grids as a `Behavior<Grid>` and you add it to your xaml.

The `Behavior<Grid>` can then also be put under unit test separately.

Microsoft Blend uses this approach.

e.g.

`public class DynamicColumn : Behavior<Grid> {}`

and you use it like this

```
<Grid>
   <Interaction.Behaviors>
      <DynamicColumn />
   </Interaction.Behaviors>
<Grid>
```

You can find more info here: https://www.wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html